# Communicating Through a View Hierarchy in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have set myself a challenge to build a basic calculator app (with similar functionality to the default Apple calculator) in order to teach myself about ios development with swift. I have a working app but the keypad is manually laid out directly in my view storyboard, and I thought to make the challenge more interesting (and the project cleaner) I would build the keypad as a custom component by subclassing UIView.

I have managed to get something working, and the keypad renders nicely. However, I now find myself with a problem that I am not sure how to solve. When the user presses one of the keypad buttons, this usually updates the output in the UI. When the buttons were direct members of my Storyboard, this was easy because I could connect the buttons up to actions in the View Controller. Now, however, I can connect the buttons actions up to my subclass of UIView, but how do I then pass this information up the View hierarchy so that the View Controller can then set the appropriate outputs elsewhere in the UI?

I know that UIViews have actions which I can connect up to the View Controller code, but I cannot find how to create custom actions, if at all possible, and then how to invoke them. Is this possible? Is there some other, standard way of doing this?

Here is my class' code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class KeypadView: UIView {
    typealias keyParams = (title: String, leading: String, top: String, color: UIColor)

    let keys: [keyParams] = [(title: "1", leading: "-1", top: "-1", color: .gray),
                             (title: "2", leading: "1", top: "-1", color: .gray),
                             (title: "3", leading: "2", top: "-1", color: .gray),
                             (title: "+", leading: "-2", top: "-1", color: .systemBlue),
                             (title: "4", leading: "-1", top: "1", color: .gray),
                             (title: "5", leading: "4", top: "2", color: .gray),
                             (title: "6", leading: "5", top: "3", color: .gray),
                             (title: "-", leading: "-2", top: "+", color: .systemBlue),
                             (title: "7", leading: "-1", top: "4", color: .gray),
                             (title: "8", leading: "7", top: "5", color: .gray),
                             (title: "9", leading: "8", top: "6", color: .gray),
                             (title: "×", leading: "-2", top: "-", color: .systemBlue),
                             (title: "C", leading: "-1", top: "7", color: .systemRed),
                             (title: "0", leading: "C", top: "8", color: .gray),
                             (title: "=", leading: "0", top: "9", color: .systemGreen),
                             (title: "÷", leading: "-2", top: "×", color: .systemBlue)]

    var buttonDict: [String: UIButton] = [String: UIButton]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButtons()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButtons()
    }

    func setupButtons() {

        for key in keys {
            let button = UIButton()
            button.setTitle(key.title, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = key.color
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

            buttonDict[key.title] = button

            addSubview(button)

            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true

            if(key.leading == "-1") {
                button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            } else if (key.leading == "-2") {
                button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            } else {
                if let leadingButton = buttonDict[key.leading] {
                    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
                }
            }

            if(key.top == "-1") {
                button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            } else {
                if let topButton = buttonDict[key.top] {
                    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
                }
            }

            //button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
            //button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("\(sender.titleLabel?.text) was pressed")
    }

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: You would typically use a delegation pattern - Your keypad view would invoke a delegate method to pass details about the button that was tapped.

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name your types starting with an uppercase letter `KeyParams` btw It would be better to use an enumeration instead of an array and a structure instead of tuples.

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. Could you elaborate on what you mean by using an enumeration instead of an Array?

Comment: @Luke maybe something like `enum Key {
    case zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, plus, minus, multiplication, division, equal
}
struct Parameter {
    let title: String, leading: String, top: String
    let color: UIColor
}

let keys: [Key: Parameter] = [.one: .init(title: "1", leading: "-1", top: "-1", color: .gray), ...]`
and accessing them would be 
`keys[.one]`

Comment: Regarding the post below I would create a protocol `CalculatorViewControllerDelegate`. If you would like to access your enumeration keys in a loop you can declare the enumeration `enum Key: CaseIterable {` and get all cases `for key in Key.allCases {
    print(keys[key]!)
}` You can also choose an specific order in your enum to fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are countless ways to make a calculator app, in any language or framework, obviously. To help illustrate the capabilities of Swift and UIKit, I threw together some things to show you what you *could* do, should you choose.

First thing you could consider is subclassing the buttons themselves so that they can carry more type-safe information.

```
class CalculatorButton: UIButton {

    var type: CalculatorButtonType?
    var integer: Int?
    var operation: CalculatorOperation?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

}
```

In order for this to work, however, you'd need to declare some enumerations.

```
enum CalculatorButtonType {
    case integer, operation
}

enum CalculatorOperation {
    case add, subtract, divide, multiply
}
```

And so when you instantiate your keypad buttons, you can inject them with relevant and type-safe information.

```
class KeypadView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: CalculatorViewController?

    private func addButtons() {

        let plusButton = CalculatorButton()
        plusButton.type = .operation
        plusButton.operation = .add
        plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        let oneButton = CalculatorButton()
        oneButton.type = .integer
        oneButton.integer = 1
        oneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc private func buttonPressed(_ sender: CalculatorButton) {

        switch sender.type {

        case .operation:
            delegate?.didTapOperation(sender.operation)

        case .integer:
            delegate?.didTapInteger(sender.integer)

        default:
            break

        }

    }

}
```

One thing this keypad view also has is a delegate, of type the view controller it's coming from. You could make this delegate of type a protocol, which the view controller can conform to. But if only one view controller is using this custom keypad, no point in creating a protocol.

And the reason we set up this delegate is so that it can communicate with the view controller when buttons are tapped.

```
class CalculatorViewController: UIViewController {

    private let keypad = KeypadView()

    func addKeypad() {
        keypad.delegate = self // this establishes the delegate relationship
    }

    func didTapInteger(_ n: Int?) {

        guard let n = n else {
            return
        }
        print(n)

    }

    func didTapOperation(_ o: CalculatorOperation?) {

        guard let o = o else {
            return
        }
        print(o)

    }

}
```

I've never made a calculator app before and if I did I have no idea if this is even how I'd go about it. And this is a very crude display of code that would require more nuance. But this should help illustrate how Swift and UIKit work and the things you can do with them.

Also notice the use of `private` access control modifiers. Get in the habit of using them. If a method or a property is never accessed from outside the object, mark it `private`. You could mark the enums `fileprivate`, for example, if they aren't used outside of the Swift file.

Comment: Thanks. The thought of subclassing UIButton had crossed my mind, but I tend to take a sort of top-down approach to development, getting things to a working state first before hammering out details of implementation later. It looks like the delegation pattern is what I was after. Thank you. I'm not very familiar with this, but coming from C# where there's quite a heavy emphasis on events, this looks kind of like the reverse of that.

Comment: To move data forward, in any language and framework, dependency injection is the obvious. To move data backward in iOS, the delegate pattern is by far the most common, and what Apple most often recommends. To move data in any direction to far away objects, Apple relies a lot on the `Notification` framework. The `Combine` framework was just introduced which is an evolution of `Notification` that allows more advanced pub-sub relationships. But the bulk of iOS development, particularly in Apple's example code, is delegate and notification.